# Is there a list displaying the champions in order based on their auto attack range?

Tags: league-of-legends

I quite enjoy playing harassing champs on LoL, and I am interested in which champions have the longest auto attack range. Is there a list displaying the order of champions with the highest range first? I cannot seem to find this resource anywhere.

From the top of my head I know Caitlyn, Annie and Ashe probably have the longest, but I know I will be missing some.

(I don't want to include skill range, or things such as Sivir's bouncing blade, I just want the raw range)

Comment: I'm not sure these kind of information are avalaible, so you'll probably end up with a subjective list. Still interested if numbers are avalaible somewhere. ^^

Comment: Why was Annie listed as long range? Is that really true?

Comment: @Sadly Not it is, she has the second longest in the game if you look at Drake's answer!

Comment: @Sadly Not - that's why most Annie guide mention auto-attack harassing in the laning phase. Even without AD, that range lets her chip away at other squishy mids.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have created an Excel file matching data from [Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki) and [LoL Builder](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.devmys.lolbuilderlite) Android app.

When I will finish all cross-checks maybe I will post the file in some online repository; in the meanwhile here it is the list of champions ordered by auto attack range:

```
Champion          Range
Kog'maw (lvl 5 W) 710 (from 500)
Tristana (lvl 18) 703
Jinx (lvl 5 Q)    700 (from 525)
Caitlyn           650
Anivia            600
Ashe              600
Zilean            600
Annie             575
Varus             575
Ziggs             575
Zyra              575
Ahri              550
Brand             550
Cassiopeia        550
Corki             550
Draven            550
Ezreal            550
Elise             550 (human)
Heimerdinger      550
Jhin              550
Kennen            550
Lissandra         550
Lucian            550
Lulu              550
Lux               550
Malzahar          550
Miss Fortune      550
Nami              550
Ryze              550
Sona              550
Soraka            550
Syndra            550
Tristana (lvl 1)  550 (+9 /lvl)
Twitch            550
Vayne             550
Karma             525
Kayle (active E)  525
LeBlanc           525
Nidalee           525
Graves            525
Orianna           525
Quinn             525
Twisted Fate      525
Veigar            525
Viktor            525
Xerath            525
Bard              500
Jayce             500 (cannon)
Kindred           500
Kog'Maw           500
Sivir             500
Swain             500
Teemo             500
Fiddlesticks      480
Janna             475
Karthus           450
Thresh            450
Vladimir          450
Urgot             425
Morgana           400
```

all other champions have a range of 200 or less.

Comment: perhaps send that excel up to google cloud as a google spreadsheet? =)

Comment: I know this could be a few months old, but xerath has also a great range for auto attack and his Q is epic especially with his W spell

Comment: so are we just gonna keep updating this answer every time a new ranged champion is released?

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that Twitch has a range of 875 with his R active.

Comment: Its definitely worth noting for everyone to understand just how small of a difference 100 extra range is on any champ. Teemo, that little bugger we all love to hate/hate to love, has an ingame character model roughly the size of what equates to 100 range for an attack. So for example, caitlyn has a range of 650, she can hit someone up to a maximum of 6 and 1/2 teemo's away.

Comment: I added some missing ranged champs like Ahri, Jayce, Lucian, Jinx, Lissandra, Elise, Nami, Syndra, Karma, etc. and also updated some old ranges, according to lolwiki, now Kog'Maw has better range than Tristana.

Comment: @Fabián could you also add the range for Jinx's rocket? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I'm ordering the champs by their base level range.

(650) Alright, well **Caitlyn** is definitely one especially with her passive a great auto attack harasser.

(600) **Ashe**, with her passive getting that first 100% crit on the enemy and with a volley is almost 3/4 their health.

(550 + 9/level) Depenging on the level, **Tristana** is a good one also since her passive gives her more and more range the higher the level so she may not be the best harasser early game. She starts with 550 range and ends with 703.

(550) **Miss Fortune** not only has decent range but she also has a very fast animation which makes for great harassing you can get an attack off before the opposing.

(550) **Corki** is another with a great passive for harassing since he will deal an addition 10% damage.

I know you mentioned you don't want to use spells but **Kog'Maw** has to be mentioned.

(500) **Kog** with the use of his 'W' (Bio Arcane Barage) he increases his range by 130 / 160 / 190 / 220 / 250 , depending on his level and does additional damage base on the targets max health.

Comment: Could you be kind enough to provide an additionnal link to your source, please? That point aside, really good answer.

Comment: @Lysarion Here is the link, just got it from the [Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki)

Comment: Twitch + Spray and Pray probably bears mentioning as well.

Comment: @Raven True, didn't even think of that.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Shame Twitch is such a glass cannon.

Comment: You missed Annie with 625.

Answer (score 3):

There is a list on **LoLWiki** which can be ordered for any criteria you like.

It lists all stats - *I think* - so you can compare them easily. Here it is: [lol champion stats](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Base_champion_statistics)

Answer (score -1):

Longest Attackrange have : Tristana, Miss Fortune, Anivia

Comment: Sorry I was asking for numbers, but you are right I did miss those, especially Tristana.